# I need to create users inside a telegram bot

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm creating a telegram bot (to sell Books), I'm using mongodb + express to handle crud how can I manage user auth?

I already have a book model containing informations about the book.

I need a user model containing basic information (like telegram @, an array of books being selled by this user)